# How is the Advance Earned Income Tax Credit (Advance EITC) supposed to work? Help!

Tags: united-states, paycheck

As a working mom of four and a full time college student I am broke. I looked into Advanced EIC and filled out the form to get an Advance EIC added to my paycheck. I picked up my check today and had 70.00 deducted with EIC-3 beside it.  My employer told me that is how it works and basically take it or leave it.  From everything I have researched about this, there is not suppose to be anything taken out. Now I can't even afford gas to get to school this week and my boss refuses to fix this problem and act as if I may loose my job if I keep on questioning them.  What should I do? Is the Advance really worth it or should I just change it back and hope they add the 70.00 back on my w-2 at the end of the year?

Answer (score 4):

Your employer obviously does not understand Advanced EIC. The idea is for you to get MORE in your paycheck and get your earned income credit throughout the year instead of all at once. Go to this link on the [IRS EITC Home Page](http://www.irs.gov/eitc) It will tell what your employer needs to do to give you EIC. Did you complete a W-5 to give to him? Hopefully if you give him this link or print it out for him he will understand how to do this. If not, then you may need to report him to the IRS. Good Luck!